# Transferring of printer settings to another windows installation

Tags: printing

is it possible to transfer printer settings to another windows installation?
I mean the settings you can set and save in any printing dialog (printing preferences).

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

#### Exporting the Configuration to a File

> 1. Press "Windows-X" to open the Power User menu and click "Command Prompt" to launch the Command Prompt utility. The default working
>    folder is your user folder.
> 2. Type "cd Desktop" (without the quotation marks) into the Command Prompt and press "Enter" to change the working directory to the
>    Desktop. You can locate the configuration file quickly on the desktop.
>    In case you changed your default working directory, provide a complete
>    path to get to the desktop: "cd c:\Users\Your_Username\Desktop" and
>    press "Enter." If your default working directory is on a different
>    partition, type "c:" and press "Enter" to change the partition and
>    then change the working directory to Desktop.
> 3. Type printui.exe /Ss /n "Printer_Name" /a "File_Name" into the Command Prompt. The "/Ss" parameter exports all printer settings to a
>    binary file specified by the "/a" parameter. The "/n" parameter
>    specifies the name of the target printer.
> 4. Replace "Printer_Name" with the name of the printer. To get the name of the printer, type "Devices and Printers" on the Start screen
>    and click the "Devices and Printers" entry; all installed printers are
>    listed in the Printers and Faxes section. Replace "File_Name" with the
>    name you want to give to the configuration file -- "configuration.dat"
>    for example. Use quotes around the printer name and file name if the
>    names contain more than one word. Press "Enter" to run the command and
>    export all settings to the file and then transfer the file to the
>    second computer and place it on the Desktop.

---

#### Importing the Configuration From the File

> 1. Launch the Command Prompt utility on the second computer and change the working folder to the Desktop using the "cd" command.
> 2. Type printui.exe /Sr /n "Printer_Name" /a "File_Name" into the Command Prompt. The "/Sr" parameter restores all information contained
>    in the file specified by the "/a" parameter. The "/n" parameter
>    specifies the name of the target printer.
> 3. Replace "Printer_Name" with the name of the printer. Again, you can get the name from the Printers and Faxes section of the Devices
>    and Printers window. Replace "File_Name" with the name of the file
>    that contains the printer configuration. Again, use quotes around the
>    printer name and file name if the names contain more than one word.
>    Press "Enter" to import the settings from the file.
> 4. View the settings to ensure everything was imported successfully. Open the Devices and Printers window, right-click the printer and
>    click "Printing Preferences." To view the advanced settings, click the
>    "Advanced" button.

Source [How to Copy a Printer's Configuration to Another Machine](http://www.ehow.com/how_8085895_copy-printers-configuration-another-machine.html)