How to change the Printer Model in Device Options within the Printer Properties via Registry
I am trying to change the printer model displayed in the Device Options section of the Printer Properties for various drivers.

I’ve already tried PowerShell modules such as PrinterConfiguration, PrinterProperties but that field is not showing up there. I also tried monitoring registry changes on saving using Procmon to track what gets updated but modifying the DriverName in the following sections hasn't had any effect:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Printers\MyPrinter\PrinterDriverData


Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\MyPrinter\PrinterDriverData

I’ve also tried restarting the print spooler and even rebooting the system after making changes, but it won't change. I've read about the DEVMODE structure, but I'm unsure if i need it for this task. Are there other locations in the registry or additional steps I’m missing?

The "Model" field in the printer properties is just the name of the driver, which you can see pretty easily in:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\MyPrinter\
Name:  Printer Driver
Type:  REG_SZ
Value: MyDriver

You can change the driver in:

The user interface under Printer Properties > Advanced > Driver

Or with powershell: Set-Printer -Name 'MyPrinter' -DriverName 'MyDriver Generic XYZ'


Those options should also update other properties like "PrinterDriverData" in the registry if needed

None of my printers/drivers show a "device options" section, but there are some additional printer properties you can set via WMI like so:
# get printer object by name
$printer = Get-WmiObject win32_printer -filter "Name='MyPrinter'"

# list all available properties
$printer | Format-List -property *

# change a property
$printer.EnableBIDI = $true

# save changes
$printer.Put()


Thanks for your answer. I’ve attached a screenshot for reference. The value only appears within the keys mentioned in the original question, and I can’t modify it through the registry. The DriverName you mentioned doesn’t match the one I referred to. This might be specific to the Samsung driver, though I’ve seen this field in other drivers as well.

@hakim00 I don't have one with settings like that to compare, but I've added another method with some extra options. You can also backup/restore all of that printer's settings with printui.exe like in the answer here: https://superuser.com/a/883345/673426, which can be much easier when transferring settings to a new PC for example
